# IE7 Nivo Slideshow weird dotted underline on caption

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, nivo-slider

I have Nivo Slideshow running on a site. When I test in the dreaded IE7 it shows a dotted underline on the captions. I have tired to find the offender in Inspect Element but no luck so far. Here is the website:

http://clintongreen.com/clients/researchreview/

Please help if you can

Cheers

Comment: Ha, got it. The Nivo default style was adding that style in, picked it up using Chrome. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Nivo style adds bottom-border:1px dotted #fff; to the caption a tags. My styling overwrote this in all browsers except IE7 and I couldn't find what was causing it through IE Dev tools, eventually I picked it up through Chrome and deleted that style attribute. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Its a known issue, I've also checked my site in IE7 and noticed the bug, but when I actually went to the official nivo-slider site Iv'e also seen those lines all across the image, I guess its not ment to work perfectly on IE7.

It happens when you use lower resolution in you windows.

Comment: Thought you were talking about the image lines, never mind :)